# Table Cloud Storage gives exception The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Tags: azure-storage

I am having an issue with Querying Azure Table Storage-

```
  public List<SubCategoryModel> GetSubCategories()
        {
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connStr);
            CloudTableClient client = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            CloudTable table = client.GetTableReference("SubCategories");

            List<SubCategoryModel> subCategoryModels = new List<SubCategoryModel>();
            TableQuery<SubCategoryEntity> subCategoriesQuery = table.CreateQuery<SubCategoryEntity>();
            var query = (from subCategory in subCategoriesQuery
                         select subCategory).AsTableQuery();
            var subCategories = query.Execute();
            foreach (SubCategoryEntity entity in subCategories)
            {
                SubCategoryModel subCategoryModel = new SubCategoryModel();
                subCategoryModel.CATEGORYID = entity.CategoryId;
                subCategoryModel.DESCRIPTION = entity.Description;
                subCategoryModel.SUBCATEGORY = entity.SubCategoryName;
                subCategoryModel.SUBCATEGORYID = entity.SubCategoryId;
                subCategoryModels.Add(subCategoryModel);
            }
            return subCategoryModels;
        }
```

web.config:

```
<add name="ConnString" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://127.0.0.1"></add>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops My Bad...I was getting the error because my Table Name was SubCategory.
And I had SubCategories Written in code.

My Bad. Fixed it. Yes!!